# App crashes if SQLite cursor has no results

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-sqlite

I have an app that uses a cursor to run an SQlite query.

```
    public Cursor totaltrips(){
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * AS TTotal FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

The results are stored to an Arraylist with a maximum of 5 values. If there are no records in the database the app crashes. If I have one or more database entries it works fine. Does anyone know how I can stop it from crashing when there are no database entries?

```
 // get column value
    if (Distance.moveToNext())
        result = String.valueOf(Distance.getDouble(Distance.getColumnIndex("myTotal")));

    tnmView.setText(result);

    List<String> distancearray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor =  dbManager.totaldistance();


    do{
        distancearray.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }while ((cursor.moveToNext()));
    ttrips = cursor.getCount();
    Log.i("Graph", "TTRIPS = " + ttrips);

    // Be sure here to have at least the 5 desired elements into the list
    while(distancearray.size() < 5){
        distancearray.add("0");
    }
```

The app crashes with the error

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

On the line

```
do{
        distancearray.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }while ((cursor.moveToNext()));
```

Comment: before that you can check cursor.getCount() > 0 ...

Comment: just add your do while loop into if/else statement `if(curser.getCount()>0){ //do-while loop here}`

Comment: just check cursor.getCount() > 0 before you do while looping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if cursor actually has results, try something like this for example:

```
int numResults = cursor.getCount();
if (numResults > 0) {
    do {
        distancearray.add(cursor.getString(1));
    } while ((cursor.moveToNext()));
}
```

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
do{
    distancearray.add(cursor.getString(1));
}while ((cursor.moveToNext()));
```

with

```
if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        distancearray.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if cursor is null and has more than one value.Close cursor after uses.

```
if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0){
cursor.moveToFirst();
while(cursor.hasNext()){

//do stuff here
}

cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: This will skip past the first row.